# How to achieve the fastest random element lookup in Python?

Tags: python, list, random, lookup

I have a list where it contains 3 lists each containing 8192, 16384, and 16384 number of 16-byte long bytes object respectively. I want to randomly select N number of elements from this list. What I have done is this:

```
mydata = bytes()
for i in range(N):
    sel1 = fastrand.pcg32bounded(3)
    sel2 = fastrand.pcg32bounded(len(mylist[sel1]))
    mydata += mylist[sel1][sel2]
```

I have used `fastrand` to increase the speed of random number generation and it worked. However, still I need more speed. Is there any way I can achieve more speed? I have also tried dictionaries like this but it turned out slower.

```
# convert list to dictionary
mydict = {}
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    keys = range(len(mylist[i]))
    mydict[i] = dict(zip(keys, mylist[i]))

mydata = bytes()
for i in range(N):
    sel1 = fastrand.pcg32bounded(3)
    sel2 = fastrand.pcg32bounded(len(mydict[sel1]))
    mydata += mydict[sel1][sel2]
```

It is not forced to have a list as a initial data struct. If any other data structure (maybe sets?) is more useful for my purpose, I can convert the list to any other datatype beforehand, no problem.

Comment: Do a partial Fisher-Yates shuffle?  Or just shuffle and take the first N elements?

Comment: Have you measured what the slow part is? I bet extending a `bytes` one byte at a time will not be fast - consider eg a Numpy byte array to fill up.

Comment: How large is N?

Comment: @AKX `bytearray`

Comment: What's the current speed and what speed do you need?

Comment: @PeterO. I do not know what it is but I will certainly look for it.

Comment: @AKX I have narrowed it down to this level but I do not know further, I will check. Do you have anything to suggest? I need a long ```bytes``` object at the end.

Comment: @KellyBundy I am sending this ```bytes``` object, ```mydata```, using TCP and I get about 150 Mbps throughput. I need 1 Gbps.

Comment: How large is N?

Comment: @KellyBundy Bigger the better. I am thinking about between 1000 and 2000, but it may go higher to around 10000 if possible.

Comment: "I want to randomly select N number of elements from this list." - Do you in fact care if the same element is selected more than once? Because *your current code will not handle this*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No, I wouldn't care. They will be selected many times, but randomly.

Answer (score 2):

`bytes` are immutable, making `+=` slow, especially for large N. Try `bytearray` instead:

```
mydata = bytearray()
```

If you really need `bytes` at the end, do this at the end:

```
mydata = bytes(mydata)
```

Put all values into one one-dimensional pool. Pure Python version using it for demo, as I can't test `fastrand`:

```
pool = 2 * mylist[0] + mylist[1] + mylist[2]
mydata = b''.join(random.choices(pool, k=N))
```

Untested with `fastrand`:

```
pool = 2 * mylist[0] + mylist[1] + mylist[2]
size = len(pool)
rand = fastrand.pcg32bounded
mydata = bytearray()
for _ in range(N):
    mydata += pool[rand(size)]
mydata = bytes(mydata)
```

Another variation, eliminating most Python interpretation:

```
from itertools import repeat
from operator import itemgetter

pool = 2 * mylist[0] + mylist[1] + mylist[2]

indices = map(fastrand.pcg32bounded,
              repeat(len(pool), N))
mydata = b''.join(itemgetter(*indices)(pool))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHLboMwEEX3/oqRsghOaRRIFaWLbLvoIqrUbiqEKgcGcIsfso0qvp4Oj7RZ1hIwHnOPfa9tHxqj90frhmEFT@ILoRI@OKFLVjmjYKzoI5U1LkwzempkSyP0Fj27SuA0N7avtNziWSj0VhQY2aLepxfT6RLL0y@EM7aCd9M5KIyuZM1U30ofiJJllz6gj5IDh8o4@ACpYdJEiudTS42t7Jg8pjEkh/3xIZ7eec7OBEh2NAh//7/BZrPGohOB4Is7GVDVGAK6eZ3mLhjT@t880KIIo40XKgWJpdHM0i90hhQ2MDvKdjncXevkpk7zUfvWIIgidKIFb9puYkhdygI9YZSw0TXg7W2Q8bJ91KKOxj15DGfOKcVSBEHKy3q9/TRSR38@os0C5rNiuoLnjkIPBnxjvukECkMjdc2sk3qGz0TOh@EH) (the last solution, with fake `fastrand`)

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I will give a try but why you have written ```2 * mylist[0]```?

Comment: Because your first list is half as large as the others, giving all its elements a twice as large chance to be chosen. My `2 *` reflects that, so they remain twice as likely.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I have tried your proposal, and I ended up almost triple times the throughput, thank you very much! I was sending packets with around 130 Mbps before, and now I can achieve around 480 Mbps! Do you have anything more to speedup even more? It should be around 1 Gbps if possible.

Comment: Was that my pure Python code or with fastrand? Also note my update at the bottom with further improvements.

Comment: With pure Python code, I have edited to something like that to send with TCP, ```CLIENT_SOCKET.sendall(b''.join(random.choices(pool, k=N)))``` and I achieve around 480 Mbps, with the fastrand I achieved around 400 Mbps .

Comment: How about the newest one with `itemgetter`?

Comment: I have tried like this ```pool = 2 * mylist[0] + mylist[1] + mylist[2]``` ```indices = map(fastrand.pcg32bounded, repeat(len(pool), N))``` ```CLIENT_SOCK.sendall(b''.join(itemgetter(*indices)(pool)))``` and got this error ```TypeError: itemgetter expected 1 argument, got 0
```.

Comment: Also, do try larger N with any of these. They have no quadratic time complexity component like your original, which I believe was slower with larger N because of that.

Comment: You should only get that error if you have N=0.

Comment: I get this error even if I replace N with literal 100.

Comment: Did you use some different `repeat` function, not the one from `itertools`?

Comment: I have written ```from itertools import repeat``` and ```from operator import itemgetter``` to top, and I also have ```import sys``` ```import os``` ```import fastrand``` ```import random``` and ```from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM```. I do not think any of these would cause this problem.

Comment: I don't see how that can happen. And I did test that code myself (just with fake fastrand). See the link I added at the bottom now. Can you run that exact demo script on your machine and tell whether you get the same error?

Comment: ```fastrand.pcg32bounded``` requires 1 argument to determine the bound, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: No, `map` does give it that argument.

Comment: Okay, I run the exact same script of your on my machine and I get no error. It printed 160000.

Comment: So then you previously did something different. Figure out what :-)

Comment: Did you maybe use the same `indices` multiple times?

Comment: Yes, I was using the same multiple times (I am sending packets with socket.sendall in an infinite loop), now I am not using it multiple times (I have moved ```indices``` inside the loop) and it works! I can achieve throughput between 600-800 Mbps, thanks! If I have an ethernet port capable of 40Gbps, what should I do in this case to achieve this kind of throughput? I was thinking of creating this random bytearrays multiple times in parallel using multiprocessing in order to make them ready when needed, does this sound a good solution to you?

Comment: Also, when I try it with larger N, my throughput reduces after N=2000, I think it is related with TCP, not with the code.

Comment: I don't know about multiprocessing or your network-sending. I think my last version is as far as I can take it. Except possibly for giving up some randomness, like if it's ok to build a pool of a million 160-byte chunks built from your 16-byte chunks, and then select N/10 from those instead of N from your original pool.